# How to count one array with respect to another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Suppose I have two arrays

```
parentArry = [1,2,3] 

ChildArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to pick to element of child array from each counter of parent array.

something like this :

```
1 - 1,2
2 - 3,4
3 - 5,6
```

Here what I am trying but it is not working

```js
    parentArry = [1,2,3] 
    
    ChildArr = [1,2,3,4,5]


    for(var i=0; i<parentArry.length; i++){
     console.log(ChildArr[i] + "And" + ChildArr[i+1])
    }
```

Comment: I see nothing in the two arrays that seem to match your output or description of the process

Comment: On the first irretaion i want to pick first and second and on second I wann pickthird and 4th. @mplungjan

Comment: Where does the 0 come from, why do you run 4 times when you only have 3 items in the parentArry? And your comment does not match your expected output either

Comment: I assume your issue isn't simply that you're misspelling `console.log` in your for loop there?

Comment: @mplungjan I have uodate the question. That was the logic i had explained

Comment: Java != Javascript!

Comment: @MCEmperor yes i know sir :) But wann solution of array so i thought it may ds problem for me which will larger ppl to get notice so i tag.

Comment: Output should be `1,2 ; 2,3 ; 3,4` according to the logic you provided. Please edit and add the current output and the expected output (and why it should come as the expected output).

Comment: @David You **should not** do that.

Comment: @MCEmperor I will keep in mind.

Comment: @mplungjan and @brioshjee I have update o/p : `1,2;3,4;5,6`

Comment: If you want output: `1and2, 3and4, 4and5`, then just change `i++` in your for loop to `i=i+2`

Comment: @briosheje I have update the question.

Comment: @David that doesn't make any sense. Where does the `6` come from?

Comment: `3 - 5,6` there is no `6` in the `ChildArr`

Comment: @briosheje Sorry that was typo.

Comment: @David  Please remember to accept my answer if this solves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my guess - it is long winded but can handle the 5 items which were present when I started coding

```js
const parentArry = [1, 2, 3]
const childArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let cnt = 0;
parentArry.forEach(item => {
  const res = [childArr[cnt]], next = childArr[++cnt];
  if (next) res.push(next);
  console.log(item,"-",res.join(","));
  cnt++;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for to get your expected output:

```js
parentArry = [1,2,3] 
    
ChildArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]


for(var i=0; i<parentArry.length; i++){
 console.log(ChildArr[i*2] + "And" + ChildArr[i*2+1])
}
```

Comment: Not sure how it does make sense and whether it will work with other datasets, but considering how many times the question changed and how many times the output changed I would say that this is pretty fair.

Comment: 5 items will give `5Andundefined`

Comment: @mplungjan OP said that having a 5 element array was a typo

Comment: OP said a lot of things ;)

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you're looking for is `n` windows of size `m` where n is given by the parent array and you are generating windows from the child array.

This question is somewhat vague, but if you must approach this problem using these two arrays as such, you could do something like:

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let first;
let second;
wsize = 2
for (var i = 0; i < a.length + wsize; i = i + wsize) {

    first = b[i]; // could be undefined
    second = b[i + 1]; // could also be undefined
    if (first !== undefined && second !== undefined) {
        console.log(b[i] + " and " + b[i + 1])
    } else if (first !== undefined) {
        console.log(b[i])
    } else break

}
```

This is clearly an instructional answer. It is verbose and not very elegant. You'll need to be aware that the length of the first array may result in the production of `undefined` for the values of `first` and `second` If the length of the child array is not divisible by length of the parent array or if the parent array is longer than the child array).

There are better solutions for windowing as well which are flexible enough to handle arbitrary window sizes and arbitrary length child arrays.

What would a more elegant solution look like?

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const wsize = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length + wsize; i = i + wsize) {
  console.log(b.slice(i, i + wsize).join(" , "))
}
```